# Запутанная структура обращения к элементам

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, dict

Есть вот такие структуры данных:

```
list_1 = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Д', 'Ф', 'А', 'К', 'О', 'Н', 'Е', 'Ё', 'И', 'Л', 'Д', 'Ж', 'Э', 'Т', 'А', 'П', 'Р', 'Н', 'Л']

list_2 = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ф', 'К', 'О', 'Н', 'И', 'Л', 'Ж', 'Э', 'Т', 'П', 'Р']

list_3 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

dict_1 = {'А': 3, 'Б': 4, 'В': 5, 'Г': 6, 'Д': 7, 'Е': 8, 'Ё': 9, 'Ф': 10, 'К': 11, 'О': 12, 'Н': 13, 'И': 14, 'Л': 15, 'Ж': 16, 'Э': 17, 'Т': 18, 'П': 19, 'Р': 20}

dict_2 = {}
```

list_1 = [фрагменты текста, некоторые из них повторяются]

list_2 = [те же элементы, что и в list_1, но уже без повторений]

list_3 = [последовательность чисел по количеству равная количеству элементов в list_2]

dict_1 = {зипованный словарь из list_2 и list_3 (для присвоения каждому элементу списка list_2 уникального числового идентификатора)}

dict_2 = Здесь на выводе нужно получить словарь вот такой структуры

```
{'А' : [4, 11, 19], 'Б' : [5], 'В' : [6], 'Г' : [7], 'Д' : [8, 10, 16], .......}
```

где ключи - это все элементы списка list_2, а значения - числовые идентификаторы присвоенные значениям в dict_1, но не числовые идентификаторы непосредственно элемента, который записывается в ключ dict_2, а идентификаторы, которые в dict_1 соответствуют элементам, которые в list_1 располагаются следующими после элемента, который записывается в ключ dict_2, а так как в list_1 некоторые элементы повторяются, следовательно и идентификаторов может быть несколько.

Как лучше всё это организовать?

Comment: А если `list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']`, то `dict_2 = {'a': [2, 2], b: [1]}` или `{'a': [2], b: [1]}`? В общем мы записываем повторяющиеся идентификаторы?  А вообще код выглядит примерно так: `dict_2 = {s: [] for s in list_2}; for i in range(len(list_1) - 1): dict_2[list_1[i]].append(dict_1[list_1[i + 1]])`.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то похожее на истину, буду пробовать!

Comment: Что касается записи повторяющихся идентификаторов - это не возможно ввиду вводимых изначально данных, после повторяющегося текста обязательно будет другой, не тот, что шёл за ним в первый раз.

Comment: Что-то не то, получаю KeyError: 0

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так (у меня с вашим примером дает нужный результат):

```
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_1[1:]):
    dict_2[i] = dict_2.get(i, []) + [dict_1[j]]
    
dict_2
'''
{'А': [4, 11, 19],
 'Б': [5],
 'В': [6],
 'Г': [7],
 'Д': [8, 10, 16],
 'Е': [9, 9],
 'Ё': [7, 14],
 'Ф': [3],
 'К': [12],
 'О': [13],
 'Н': [8, 15],
 'И': [15],
 'Л': [7],
 'Ж': [17],
 'Э': [18],
 'Т': [3],
 'П': [20],
 'Р': [13]}
```

Comment: Благодарю! сейчас попробуем

Comment: Это то, что нужно!!! Спасибо огромное!!! Пытаюсь понять, как это работает.